# How to merge two branches without losing the files that are not contained on the other one?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on a project with different features, and for each one of them I created a different branch.

All my files are currently in master. But everytime I create a new branch, I delete all the files and keep only the feature related ones on these branches.

My question is: how can I merge the feature branch into the master branch without actually discarding all the other files?

e.g.: Master branch has the files login.html, menu.html and contact.html
Feature branch has the feature.html file only.

On branch master, when I execute

git merge feature

All the files are deleted from the master branch, and only the feature.html is kept, but I wanted all of them to be on the master branch, including the feature.html.

Comment: "But everytime I create a new branch, I delete all the files and keep only the feature related ones on these branches" Out of curiosity : why is that?

Comment: You could just do a `git merge --no-commit`, then get the deleted files back from the grave before committing and then you can do the `git merge --continue`... but I'm wondering: "why do you delete the files in the first place if you will eventually merge into master and then you will face exactly this problem?"

Comment: There are a lot of different features, and I don't want the whole project to be copied inside the branch everytime I create a new one! I want to keep only the feature related files inside their respective branches.

Comment: When you say "copied", what do you mean exactly? Because on git... on the DB, that is, you are not copying anything by creating a new branch.

Comment: @RodolfoRondon This seems like a misunderstanding. Git's very structure is such that objects are not duplicated. A branch is just a pointer. Create 1000 branches in your repo if you feel like it and you'll be fine.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how git works. When you create a new branch, files are not copied into it. Rather a branch is a very light-weight reference to a commit. A commit is only a record of the changes since the previous commit. As others have said, you should not delete files unless you truly want to remove them from the entire project.

Comment: If you need to focus on certain files while you work on a given feature, there are other tools than git. For example, most IDEs have features to help you focus on only the files related to a given task.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "A commit is only a record of the changes since the previous commit" Even if I agree with you on the explanation about branches, this idea of commits in git is just misleading. A commit is *not* that. Each commit actually references your whole tree at a given point, and the changes in between are reconstructed at execution when you diff two commits. But the point is, the objects at the tree leaves, blobs, are referenced multiple times if needed, and most don't change that much, so making commits only marginally inflates repo size.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* be deleting the files from the project on the new branch... but anyway, let's assume that it's a must for whatever reason. If I'm going to eventually merge the branch on master, then I would probably do a little trick to kind of avoid this problem from showing up... but it requires a little bit of additional work. I would delete the files on the first commit of the new branch and I would do nothing else on that revision. Then, when I want to merge back into master, I would not just merge, but I would cherry-pick (or rebase) discarding the commit where I deleted the files and then I would merge the rebased/cherry-picked branch.

Let's assume that I create feature1 branch from master and I do 3 revisions there... something like:

```
git checkout -b feature1 master
git rm index.html blahblah.html # delete the files I don't want to keep on the branch
git commit -m "Removing the files I don't want"
# work
git commit -m "First real revision of feature 1"
# more work
git commit -m "Second revision of feature 1"
```

At this point I'm ready to merge into master... then I would't just merge feature 1 because that would delete the files because I did that on the first revision of feature1, right?... I would discard the first revision and then merge into master, and that can be done relatively easily.

```
git checkout --detach master # go back to master
git cherry-pick feature1~2..feature1 # only cherry-pick the last 2 revisions
git checkout master # go back to master again
git merge --no-ff HEAD@{1} -m "Merging feature 1" # merge rebased branch
```

That should do. But I don't think you should delete the files anyway.

Comment: Even if the part I liked best is **But I don't think you should delete the files anyway**, I salute the straightforward and pragmatic decision to actually propose something more constructive than just a handwave to some XY problem (like I unfortunately did in some measure, even if I stand by my comment about commits). Upvoted.